# Detect common words in strings Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

How can I detect a common substring between two or more sentences in Ruby.

I have a lot of string like:

- John D
- Paul John
- John

I have to get the substring John, how can I implement this?

Thanks

Comment: I've not idea, sorry . i use Ruby from about 2 weeks and i'm not really skilled i search for suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving for the general case:

```
def count_tokens(*args)
  tokens = args.join(" ").split(/\s/)
  tokens.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|counts, token| counts[token] += 1; counts }
end

counts = count_tokens("John D", "Paul John", "John")
# => {"John"=>3, "D"=>1, "Paul"=>1}
```

This splits each string up into tokens, then counts the number of instances of each of the tokens. From there, it's trivial to sort the hash to get the most commonly-used tokens.

Comment: @Dproof If you are accepting this answer, then your question is badly worded because this answer does what is entirely different from what you are asking.

Comment: Besides the difference between substring and words, This answer does not distinguish multiple occurrences within a single original string and among multiple original strings.

Answer (score 1):

Find the most recent element, then compare it.

```
list_of_strings = ["some", "random", "strings"]

def most_common_value(a)
  a.group_by do |array_element|
    array_element
  end.values.max_by(&:size).first
end

list_of_strings.each do |array_element|
  if /^#{most_common_value(list_of_strings)}$/ =~ array_element
    puts array_element
  end
end
```

Comment: what if i don't know the word? thanks

Comment: updated for the general case

Answer (score 1):

```
def string_count(sentence)
  counts = Hash.new(0)
  str_array = sentence.downcase.scan(/[\w]+/)
  for string in str_array
    counts[string] += 1
  end
  counts
end
```

Passing in your sentence to `string_count("John D John Paul John")` 
would produce the output.

`# => {"john"=>3, "d"=>1, "paul"=>1}`

Hope this helps!